# Indentation like astyle - continuation lines

Tags: vimrc, formatting

I currently use `astyle -A8 -t8 -p -j <filename>` to format the code in my C project.

Is there a way to configure my `.vimrc` to follow the continuation line format that the above demands? For example `astyle` formats the below function call:

```
my_function(first_arg, 
<tab>second_arg,
<tab>third_arg);
```

(which is the default indentation when I hit `Enter`) as

```
my_function(first_arg, 
            second_arg,
            third_arg);
```

I saw in `cinoptions-values` there was something close:

```
                                               *cino-+*
+N    Indent a continuation line (a line that spills onto the next)
      inside a function N additional characters.  (default
      'shiftwidth').
       Outside of a function, when the previous line ended in a
       backslash, the 2 * N is used.

        cino=             cino=+10 >
          a = b + 9 *       a = b + 9 *
              c;                      c;
```

But that only aligns to a specific number of spaces. Is there a way to align it like the `astyle` example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `set cino+=(0`

```
(N    When in unclosed parentheses, indent N characters from the line
      with the unclosed parentheses.  Add a 'shiftwidth' for every
      unclosed parentheses.  When N is 0 or the unclosed parentheses
      is the first non-white character in its line, line up with the
      next non-white character after the unclosed parentheses.
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need... but is there a way to not insert a `'shiftwidth'` and instead just insert aligning spaces?

Comment: Exactly as in my answer: `set cino+=(0`.  Does this not work?

Comment: Ah I should clarify that I use tabs for C with the following: `autocmd Filetype cType setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4`. I just tried it with spaces and that's why there's an extra `'shiftwidth'`. Is there a way to make custom `cinoptions`?